# Create List<Dynamic> from List<Stuff>

Tags: list, flutter, csv, file, dart

I am trying to create a .csv file using a `List<Stuff>` type list. In order to use `ListToCsvConverter()`, I need a `List<Dynamic>`.

How do I convert a `List<Stuff>` to a `List<Dynamic>` so that I can convert it to .csv with [`ListToCsvConverter()`](https://pub.dev/packages/csv)?

"Stuff" model below:

```
class Stuff { 
  int id;
  String stuffType; 
  String stuffSize; 
  String stuffTime;
  Stuff({this.id, this.stuffType, this.stuffSize, this.stuffTime});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a clear answer for people to see.

Initial List is "stuffList".

> How do I convert a `List<Stuff>` to a `List<Dynamic>` so that I can convert it to .csv with ListToCsvConverter()?

```
//Create a new dynamic list
List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>(); 

//Convert stuffList to List<List<dynamic>>
  for (int i = 0; i < listStuff.length; i++) {
      List<dynamic> row = List();
      row.add(listStuff[i].id);
      row.add(listStuff[i].stuffType);
      row.add(listStuff[i].stuffSize);
      row.add(listStuff[i].stuffTime);
      rows.add(row);
    }

//convert the list to csv
final csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `ListToCsvConverter()` is not accepting a `List<Stuff>` but a `List<List<dynamic>>`.

The first level `List` is the list of rows for your csv, while the second level `List` is the list of cells in each row.

I added a getter `csvRow` in your `Stuff` class and map to the rows just before calling `ListToCsvConverter()`:

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  String csv = const ListToCsvConverter()
      .convert(stuffList.map((stuff) => stuff.csvRow).toList());
  print(csv);
}

class Stuff {
  int id;
  String stuffType;
  String stuffSize;
  String stuffTime;
  Stuff({this.id, this.stuffType, this.stuffSize, this.stuffTime});

  List<dynamic> get csvRow => [id, stuffType, stuffSize, stuffTime];
}

final faker = Faker();
final stuffList = List.generate(
    100,
    (index) => Stuff(
          id: faker.randomGenerator.integer(999999, min: 100000),
          stuffType: faker.person.name(),
          stuffSize: '${faker.randomGenerator.integer(1000)}MB',
          stuffTime: faker.date.toString(),
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm feeling thick headed today and having trouble understanding the code. What is "faker"? I have a List<Stuff> already.

Comment: Faker is just a package to generate random data. Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/faker

Comment: Ok, so you are just generating a List<Stuff> as "stuffList" right? Can you explain lower-case "stuff" here? stuffList.map((stuff)

Comment: `map` is applying a function to each element (`stuff`) of the list (`stuffList`) and returning an`Iterable`. You should spend some time learning about Dart and Flutter. I recommend Andrea Bizzotto, for example, his complete course on Dart language: https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-dart-guide/

Comment: I'm asking what lower case "stuff" is in this specific case. We haven't instanced anything called "stuff". A generalized Flutter/Dart course will do nothing for me in explaining what the arbitrary value "stuff" is.

Comment: Are you referring to "Stuff"?

Comment: I figured it out. Amazingly without completely re-educating myself. Will post a clear answer below, without use of random generator libraries or un-instantiated variables.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification; "The first level List is the list of rows for your csv, while the second level List is the list of cells in each row." That is valuable input. For future reference, I'd recommend not suggesting people start at ground 0 just because they are having a moment of difficulty understanding your abstract inputs.